# sizeThatFits on view with constraints (auto layout view inside frame layout view)

Tags: ios, autolayout, uikit

[image: This can't be impossible to do]

View A layouts it's subviews by calculating and setting their frames in layoutSubviews.

View B uses constraints to layout it's subviews.

View A contains a number of View B instances.

View A needs to know the size of its subviews when it layouts them, so it calls `sizeThatFits:` on them.

View B's height depends on it's width. In my example it has a multiline `UILabel` inside it.

**How should B implement it's `sizeThatFits:` so it returns the correct size taking both the `size` parameter passed to `sizeThatFits:` and the constraints in account?**

What I've tried/considered so far:

`systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:` - doesn't work because it doesn't take into account an exact size passed to it. It can't be used to specify an exact width for e.g a view that grows vertically as it shrinks horizontally. It only gives either the most compressed size or the most expanded size.

`intrinsicContentSize`- this is used to pass information ***to*** Auto Layout as far as i understand from the docs. What we want is to get information ***from*** Auto Layout.

This is how i've reasoned so far. Please correct me if i've made a mistake. And please help me, i'd be very grateful if someone could point me to how this is done!

edit: Also, maybe there is some entirely different way to do this, without even using `sizeThatFits:`? The only requirement i have is that i can continue using frame layout in the "outer" view (View A) and auto layout in the "inner view" (View B).

edit2: Added a picture to illustrate the exact case i must solve

edit3: Forgot to mention, i need to support iOS 7.0

Comment: Why don't you put constraints linking your views B to your view A and change the vertical content hugging priority of your view A to low?

Comment: Also, if you choose that way, make sure all your B views have top and bottom constraints linking all views together, so that view A will know how to resize ;)

Comment: But that would be using auto layout in View A, and i'd like to know how to be able to position the views arbitrarily using code (frame layout) in View A while using constraints in View B. Sure, the layout in the picture is easily achieved with auto layout, but sometimes the layout can't be expressed in constraints, and i'd like to learn how this is done for such situations.

Comment: I don't see anything in the layout you have illustrated which could not be expressed in constraints.

Comment: Yes that is true but, i want to learn HOW to do it for the cases where the layout *cant* be expressed only with constraints

Comment: Use autolayout, we're in 2016. You shouldn't build anything without it anyways.

Answer (score 0):

From the picture it would appear that a UIStackView might be a better approach for View A?

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStackView_Class_Reference/

and then just constrain with a margin offset the bottom of the View A UIStackView to the bottom of the last View B

Comment: UIStackView isn't available before iOS 9.0

Comment: Oh sorry i never said in the question that i need to support iOS 7.0. But really even if it was it wouldn't work, i want to be able to just set the frames to whatever i want in View A, and UIStackView does not let me set the frames to whatever i want.

Answer (score 0):

I would use Autolayout for the lot. You can still specify exact sizes and positions, you just do it with constraints instead of with frames.